# How to close QGIS polygon without a mouse?

Tags: qgis

One of my students is using a Windows laptop that does not have physical trackpad buttons; left and right clicks are completed by one and two-finger taps, respectively. The one/two-finger taps work for everything else in QGIS except closing polygons—when a two-finger tap is made (i.e., a right click), the polygon simply disappears. Is there a key command that can be used instead?

This is QGIS 3.10.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: Hold the finger down and release and you should get the action box.  Typically you can hold a press and release to get right button click choices but on my QGIS i get the action box without having to use the menu.